# Image of a precompact under the action of uniformly continuous function is a precompact

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness, uniform-continuity

**Suppose** we have two metric spaces $(X, \rho_x)$ and $(Y, \rho_y)$ and a uniformly continuous function $f\colon X \to Y$. **The problem** is to prove that image $f(A)$ of every precompact $A \subset X$ (i.e. a subspace whose closure in some larger space is compact) is also a precomact.

Comment: Your definition of precompactness is not the usual one. It is equivalent to precompactness (for every $\varepsilon>0$ the set is covered by finitely many balls of radius $\le \varepsilon$) only in complete metric spaces.

Comment: @Jochen, You right, I changed the definition